# Linux - User Display name alias in shell prompt

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, terminal, alias

Is it possible to alias the user display name in the shell prompt?

For example: When I ssh with `john123@192.168.1.2`, it displays as `John123`

`[John123@myhost ~]#`

Can I change it to a alias `csgeek` without having to rename the username?

`[csgeek@myhost ~]#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export PS1="$(echo "$PS1"|sed -e 's/\\u/csgeek/g')"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Added that to /home/john123/.profile and upon login it shows as `csgeek`